# Create a zip of archived artifacts in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a MSbuild job in jenkins running on windows slave. The master server is a linux server. When build runs successfully, i am archiving the artifacts which executes on linux master server. Now i want to create a zip of this  archived artifacts. How do i do this as  my slave is a windows slave ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different parts of each job be done on specific nodes. In your pipeline script (assuming it's groovy) after the windows portion of your job completes, add another 'node' section with the label 'master':

```
node('master')
```

Jenkins stores artifacts in the following location:

> $JENKINS_HOME/jobs//builds//archive

You can cd to that directory then perform a zip command

```
zip -r name_of_zip_file ./*
```

You should be able to add something like the snippet below to your groovy script:

```
node('master'){

    stage ("Zip Artifacts"){

    sh '''
    cd $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job>/builds/<build>/archive
    zip -r name_of_zip_file ./*
    '''
 }
}
```

Comment: No jobs are building on master node. This job is running on windows slave. so after archiving the artifacts when I try to create a zip it executes on windows slave and gives error as the artifacts needs to be zipped present on master node.

Comment: You could write `$JOB_NAME` instead of `<job>`.

Comment: ... and `lastSuccessfulBuild` instead of `<build>` if you want to reference the newest artifacts.